# WSO2 Workflow execution trace for debugging purposes

Tags: debugging, workflow, wso2, bpel

We are currently evaluating the latest **WSO2 BPS 3.0** as an open source replacement for Oracle BPEL. So far I was able to create and deploy a workflow on the BPS server. I was also able to test it and everything seem to work fine.

The problem however is looking at the **EXECUTION TRACE** like we can on the Oracle BPEL console.
I succesfuuly enabled SOAP TRACING only to see SOAP messages incoming and outgoing from the BPEL process. I however would like to see the output at each interim step of the workflow. Oracle does a wonderful job wherein I can just click on individual steps in the execution trace and view the output after each step. This is a very very important functionality and am surprised is not enabled OUT OF THE BOX.

I also tried the steps at [BPEL Designer for Eclipse: how to debug a BPEL process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103198/bpel-designer-for-eclipse-how-to-debug-a-bpel-process/10222012#10222012) but still cannot get it to work.

Can somebody list the exact steps so I can visualize the output of every step in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the input and output messages corresponding to each activity from the instance view. From the management console, go-to instance view and click on a given process instance id. Then you would get to the instance view.

Also by enabling soap tracer from the management console, you can view the incoming and outgoing soap messages.

Additionally, you can enabling message tracing at log level to log all messages coming in and going out.